# Android recovery mode

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, verizon

When I am installing the caynogenmod 12.1 on recovery 3e the verifying signature is failing. What happened in this my device. Thank you so much.

Comment: Doesn't sound like you're using a custom recovery.

Comment: Find your device  [here](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/SGS3FAQ) and follow the flashing instructions in the linked page. If you encounter any issue let us know in a new question.

Answer (score 1):

"3e" is the stock recovery, which doesn't support flashing custom ROMs. It will only accept packages signed by the manufacturer. So if you want to flash a custom ROM, you'll have to install a custom recovery first.

For details, see our [recovery-mode](/questions/tagged/recovery-mode) [tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/recovery-mode/info). For example candidates, also see [clockworkmod](/questions/tagged/clockworkmod) and [twrp](/questions/tagged/twrp). Moreover, the place where you downloaded your ROM image will have given you the necessary details. If not, head over to the [CyanogenMod Wiki on your device](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/SGS3FAQ). Once you've identified your device, check the [Download page](http://download.cyanogenmod.org/) for the image. Instructions can be found from the [Devices page](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Devices).